# "Лошадь переступала копытами" — можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость

У меня в тексте было написано "лошадь нервно переступала копытами".

Мне сказали, что так говорить нельзя. Копытами можно бить, но переступать — ногами. Можно ли оставить так, как у меня, или все-таки лучше принять к сведению замечание и исправить?

Comment: может быть "нервно перебирала копытами" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хороший вопрос, спасибо.
Хотя вообще-то тут два вопроса. Допустимо ли такое сочетание со стилистической точки зрения, и есть ли основания для такого оборота с фактической точки зрения.  Т.е. можно ли "переступать не ногами" вообще и c языковой точки зрения в частности.
И ни на один из вопросов исчерпывающего ответа я не нашел.

Сначала о лексическо-стилистическом моменте. Слух "переступать копытами" мне не режет, указаний на сочетаемость "переступать" исключительно с "ногами" я не нашел, но есть безусловное "сучит копытами", что ставит под сомнение стилистическую правильность "переступать копытами".

Теперь о физическом понимании.
*Переступать — идти, двигаться, шагать. Конь медленно переступал ногами.*
Но если можно "идти ногами", то почему нельзя копытами? Вот и в нац. корпусе встречаются подобные примеры:
*"...и пусть идёт она... узко переступая чёрными тупоносыми туфлями..."* [Татьяна Толстая. Река Оккервиль (1983)].
Чем туфли лучше копыт? Стоит ещё вспомнить, что слово "копыто" ранее относилось не только к лошадиным ногам, а вообще ко всяким ногтям (не когтям) на нижних конечностях, в том числе и человеческих...

Короче так. Запрета на "переступать копытами" я не вижу. Но логичнее все-таки употребить "сучить копытами" и "переступать ногами". Если, конечно, автор не собирается внести умышленную фигуру речи (даже не знаю, как её назвать в данном случае, своего рода метонимия, наверное).

Comment: "слово "копыто" ранее относилось не только к лошадиным ногам, а вообще ко всяким ногтям (не когтям) на нижних конечностях, в том числе и человеческих"

в самом деле?

Answer (score 1):

может, не по теме немного, но мне "переступала ногами" глаз режет, "копытами" как-то приятнее звучит, имхо

Comment: по-моему, тоже

Comment: можно вообще "переступала с ноги на ногу" - может, так лучше?

Comment: ...с одной на другую, третью, четвертую...

Comment: Нет, вообще-то в таких ситуациях (насколько я знаю, разумеется, не не великий знаток лошадшей) задние ноги остаются неподвижными (на них вес тела в основном), а передними лошадь переступает, когда волнуется

Answer (score 0):

Копыто, как известно, у лошади является частью ноги. Поменяем лошадь на ...человека. Человек нервно переступал пятками. Забавно. Но: мальчик подошёл к замёрзшему окну, шлёпая босыми пятками по полу. Лошадь подошла к замёрзшему окну, цокая копытами по полу. Слова "ступать" и "переступать" имеют разный смысл. Сравните: ступать на цыпочках и переступать на цыпочках? Лошадь шла, мягко ступая копытами по заросшей мхом тропе. Замечание сделано верно, стоит принять к сведению.

Comment: Если ступать копытами можно, отчего же ими нельзя переступать? Что за парадоксы, позвольте спросить.

Answer (score 0):

**У меня в тексте было написано "лошадь нервно переступала копытами".**

Это выражение часто встречается в произведениях писателей, чувство языка которых не вызывает сомнений. Приведу для примера две цитаты:

> *Пески горели страшно, огонь почти сразу объял захламленные жилища
>   бедняков, **лошадь под императором нервно переступала копытами** среди
>   узлов всякого жалкого барахла, ветоши, самоваров и горок посуды...*
>   (Валентин Пикуль)
>
> *Тихо сделалось, только огонь потрескивал да **переступала копытами
>   лошадь**.* (Владислав Крапивин)